# error : GDB failed with message: not in executable format: file format not recognized

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, gdb

I am trying to run C ++ code in Visual Studio Code. But when you start debugging, the following error is displayed:

```
Unable to start debugging. Program path '/home/user/0/hlw2' is missing or invalid.
GDB failed with message: "/home/user/0/hlw2": not in executable format: file format not recognized
This may occur if the process's executable was changed after the process was started, such as when installing an update. Try re-launching the application or restarting the machine.
```

GDB version:

```
gdb --v
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

GCC version :

```
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
```

when trying to compile a file in terminal via GCC:

```
gcc -g -o hlw2 hlw2.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc40XHIQ.o: in function `main':
/home/user/0/hlw2.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/0/hlw2.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/0/hlw2.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/0/hlw2.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc40XHIQ.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/usr/include/c++/9/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Use `g++` instead of `gcc` to compile C++ programs

Comment: @Woodford , i can't select g ++ in VSCode. I can choose "launch gdb", "attach gdb" or "cpp build and debug active file".
But on another computer, having installed VSCode, I was able to select g ++ (nothing but setting it up). Perhaps a package is not installed?

Comment: You're mixing up your launch.json (debugging) with tasks.json (build tasks). Typically, the gdb profile you select has an entry for the build task to call. You then need to ensure that the build task is configured correctly.